# Auto Filling Post fields

Tags: posts

I'd like to be able to automatically fill all of a post's fields (Title, excerpt, even fields created by plugins such as PowerPress, for example). 
For example, I've got a spreadsheet with the title, body, excerpt, etc. - and I wish to open a new post with the values from the sheet populated in the post.

Any idea on how I can do that? a plugin, perhaps? maybe using the API? (although I think the REST interface won't let me fill non-standard fields created by plugins, right?)
Thanks! 
RL

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a few plugins for that around. [Ultimate CSV Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/) looks like a good fit. Just make sure that your column titles in your spreadsheet match what the plugin is expecting. That is, if it needs the column to be named "post_title" in order to set the title, setting the column name to "title" won't work.